# How to be safe while on terminal with root privilege?

Tags: linux, command-line

Unix & Linux shell/CLI is very flexible which gives lots of powers and privileges to its root user but it also comes with a great responsibility of executing commands correctly.

I have seen lots of people went in trouble by executing wrong commands accidentally and lost data and configured servers as it doesn't show any warning while executing the commands, the internet is full of with such cases.

So my question here is how we can be on root privilege and also very safe while using CLI?

Comment: IMHO, you can't. Just read the command line before pressing Enter.

Comment: @Kusalananda, yeah that's there but, Human is to err. few people will end up due to less knowledge and sometimes they will do it in hurry

Comment: The `root` account does not receive any warning for its actions. By definition, it can do anything and it should do so. This "no warning" situation also occurs to normal users: for example, when they run `rm file`. Many Linux distributions provide `sudo`, so that you must think about an operation, before performing it, and you must confirm it with your password. This gives you a temporary *almost* root privilege, to be renewed each time: this is an attempt to make you more *safe* in CLI in those systems.

Comment: implement a nazi selinux policy that avoid any root modification.

Comment: @BowPark Except that it's temporary **actual** root privilege `sudo` gives (after all it runs the command to be executed as `root` so by definition it's with root priveleges).

Comment: @skyking You are absolutely right. I wrote *almost* because of the customization that is possible on the configuration file `/etc/sudoers`, which can selectively prevent some users performing some operations. But if and when you are allowed to run a command, yes, you act as `root`.

Comment: @Ali786 I think the best answer is experience because you can't explain `sudo rm -rf` to a newbie. I used this twice and lost data so I am now aware of it because I have experience.

Comment: While certain OtherOS usually treats the user like an idiot, Linux expects the user to _prove it_.  ;3

Answer (score 7):

One popular way to remind yourself you're running in privileged mode is to set up your shell prompt to show your username as red. Most prompts will change to a `#` when running as root, but it's helpful to also see a "dangerous" color to know you should use caution.

Another idea is to use the principal of least privilege as much as possible. Use a tool like `sudo` to restrict your user's ability to run only a subset of commands (in a normal mode). This is also a cornerstone of the selinux patch which implements mandatory access control (MAC) on system resources. Some find selinux to be prohibitively difficult to work with, but if you learn it well, it's a very useful tool.

As others have said, there's really no way to be perfectly safe while running as `root`, so it's best to have regular backups and some procedure in place should the worst happen. We all make mistakes, but if you're able to recover from them, the mistakes don't cost you that much.

It may be a little too broad for your application, but check out GitLab's postmortem of their [database corruption incident](https://about.gitlab.com/2017/02/10/postmortem-of-database-outage-of-january-31/) last year. Specifically, [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-com/infrastructure/issues/1094) are some steps they took to set up their PS1 to indicate the "safety" of their environment.